# Trying to convert string into a integer

Tags: c++

```
    string info;
    bool flag = false;
    int n = 0;
    while (getline(fin, info))
    {
        
        stringstream ss(info);
        string temp;

        getline(ss, totalStudents[n].firstName, ',');
        getline(ss, totalStudents[n].lastName, ',');
        getline(ss, temp, ',');

        totalStudents[n].studentId = stol(temp);

        if(studentID == totalStudents[n].studentId)
        {
            flag = true;
            continue;
        }

        getline(ss, temp, ',');
        totalStudents[n].testsTaken = stoi(temp);
        totalStudents[n].testScores = new int [totalStudents[n].testsTaken];

        for(int i = 0; i < totalStudents[n].testsTaken; i++)
        {
            getline(ss, temp, ',');
            totalStudents[n].testScores[i] = stoi(temp);
        }

        n++;
    }
 
    fin.close();
```

I cannot figure out how to prevent this error after compiling and running the code.

It crashes the entire program and looks like it should work but it is not.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stol
```

here is the data file it pulls from

```
Smith,John Stevens,12456214,5,99,98,96,92,91,
Johnson,Chris,11058975,4,84,83,78,91,
abcd,abcd,11114444,4,100,100,100,98,

William,Euan,12121,80,90,80,70,90,
John,Smith,78506,90,80,90,68,78,
Jack,Jack,12345,85,95,78,89,65,
```

Comment: Have you examined the input you are giving to `stol` with a debugger?

Comment: I am still new to coding, how do I use a debugger?

Comment: Depends on your IDE or debugger. If you use Visual Studio learn what the F9, F10 and F11 keys do. Also when the code stops learn how to look at the variables involved.

Comment: still fairly new to visual studio code, how would I go about using the debugger?

Comment: If you don't know how to use debugger, take pen and paper, your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and go step by step through line `William,Euan,12121,80,90,80,70,90,`

Comment: Or actually the issue is earlier, with the empty line.

Comment: Okay thanks! I added a condition to check if there was an empty line of code.

Comment: The line `William,Euan,12121,80,90,80,70,90,` says that there are 80 tests taken, but the number of test scores that follow is less than 80

Comment: Think about what the `getline(ss, ...)` calls will produce when a blank line has been read (or a line that does not comply with the expected format).  From there you can reason about what strings are being provided to `stoi()` - and, in particular, whether they would cause `stoi()` to throw an exception.    [It is quite common for people to write code reading from a file that assumes the input is exactly as expected.   It is another to write code that sensibly handles input that is NOT as expected.  I suspect you haven't really done the latter].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your input file has 2 different formats

1. A line contains the number of grades. The ID has 8 digits
2. A line does not contain any number of grades. The ID has 5 digits
3. There is an empty line between these 2 differently formatted lines

Additional observation: The number of grades is never needed. We can "see" how many grades are there.

Anyway, because we have these 2 different formats, you solution, based on the given number of grades, will not work for case 2.

You will allocate the wrong number of elements and then access out of bound array elements, which will most certainly lead to a crash.

So, we need to differentiate the 2 cases and the adapt the reading routine.

For my example below, I use the length of the ID as differentiator.

But also the empty line could be used as an indicator that from now on, option 2 shall be used.

I dis also notice that you use `new` and do selfmade dynamic memory management. By the way, if you call `new` then you need also call `delete` at some point in time.

Anyway, my conclusion is that you either do not want to aor are not allowed to use a `std::vector` which would be the appropriate choice.

I prepared a solution for you with hand written full dynamic memory management. Additionally, I have added some administrational functions to the `Student` class.

I have especially overwritten the extracor `>>` and the inserter `<<` operator for easier handling with all kind of streams. This should be always done, because the class knows, how to read and write its data. This should not be handled by general purpose functions.

Please see one of many many possible solutions below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

// A student class for storing grades with dynamic memory management
struct Student {

    // Constructor and destructor
    Student() { grades = new int[capacityForGrades]; }   // Constructor will allocate minimum memory
    ~Student() { delete[] grades; }                      // Release previously allocated memory

    // Student Data
    std::string name{};
    std::string firstName{};
    std::string id{};
    int* grades{};                                         // Array of grades. Initially 0 elements
    // Administrational values
    int numberOfGrades{0};                                 // Number of stored grades is initially 0
    int capacityForGrades{ 2 };                            // But we could store capacity grades here
    
    void addGrade(int grade) {                             // Add grades, including dynamic memory management
        if (numberOfGrades >= capacityForGrades) {         // Do we still have capacity to store a new grade?
            capacityForGrades *= 2;                        // No, double up the capcity from now on
            int* temp = new int[capacityForGrades];        // Get bigger temproaray space with new capacity
            for (int k = 0; k < numberOfGrades; ++k)       // Copy old data to new temp data
                temp[k] = grades[k];
            delete[] grades;                               // Delete memory with old data
            grades = temp;                                 // And assign new temp data to old grades pointer
        }
        grades[numberOfGrades++] = grade;                  // Store new grade and increase counter 
    }
    Student& operator=(const Student& other) {             // Copy of student with deep copy of grades
        if (this != &other) {                              // not a self-assignment
            delete[] grades;                               // release current memoryfor grades
            capacityForGrades = numberOfGrades = other.numberOfGrades;
            grades = new int[capacityForGrades];           // Get new memory, depending on size of other 
            for (int k = 0; k < numberOfGrades; ++k)       // Copy other data
                grades[k] = other.grades[k];
            name = other.name;
            firstName = other.firstName;
            id = other.id;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    // Clear existing data. Capacity will be as before
    void clear() { numberOfGrades = 0; name = {}; firstName = {}; id = {}; }
                        // 
    // Read values from any stream
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Student& s) {
        std::string line{}, dummy{}, gradeAsString{};      // Some temp strings
        if (std::getline(is, line) and not line.empty()) { // Read a none empty line
           std::istringstream iss{ line };                // Put it into an istringstream for further extraction
            std::getline(iss, s.name, ',');                // Get name
            std::getline(iss, s.firstName, ',');           // and first name
            std::getline(iss, s.id, ',');                  // and the ID
            if(s.id.length() >= 8)                         // If ID is greater then 8, we assume a follwing numberof grades
                std::getline(iss, dummy, ',');             // But actually, we do not care and ignore this
            while (std::getline(iss, gradeAsString, ','))  // Extract all grades
                s.addGrade(std::stoi(gradeAsString));      // ANd add them to our internal dynamic array
        }
        return is;
    }
    // Show result on any output stream
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Student& s) {
        os <<  std::left << "Name: " << std::setw(15) << s.name << "\tFirst name: " << std::setw(15) << s.firstName 
            << "\tID: " << std::setw(9) << s.id << "\tNumber of grades: " << s.numberOfGrades << "\twhich are: ";
        for (int k = 0; k < s.numberOfGrades; ++k)
            os << s.grades[k] << ' ';
        return os;
    }
};

struct Roster {                                               // Store many studnes dynamically

    Roster() { students = new Student[capacity]; }            // Allocate a capacity of memory, independent of numberof students
    ~Roster() { delete[] students; }                          // Release previously allocated memory

    Student* students;                                        // Dynamic array of students

    int numberOfStudents{ 0 };                                // Number of Students in Roster   
    int capacity{ 2 };                                        // Capacity of dynamic array

    void addStudent(Student& s) {                             // Add a student o our dynamic array
        if (s.numberOfGrades) {                               // But only, if there is data in it
            if (numberOfStudents >= capacity) {               // Check, if we have enough space
                capacity *= 2;                                // no, then double the capacity
                Student* temp = new Student[capacity];        // Get new memory
                for (int k = 0; k < numberOfStudents; ++k)    // Copy old data to temp data
                    temp[k] = students[k];                    // Make a deep copy
                delete[]students;                             // Release memory for old data
                students = temp;                              // And reassign temp to students dynamic array
            }
            students[numberOfStudents++] = s;                 // Store new student
        }
    }
    // Simple input routine for a student
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Roster& r) { 
        Student tempStudent{};
        while (is >> tempStudent) {                           // Call extractor operator of student
            r.addStudent(tempStudent);
            tempStudent.clear();
        }
        return is;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Roster& r) {
        for (int k = 0; k < r.numberOfStudents; ++k)          // Call inserteroperator of Student
            os << r.students[k] << '\n';
        return os;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::ifstream fileStream{ "student.txt" };
    if (fileStream) {

        Roster roster{};

        // Read all students from file
        fileStream >> roster;

        // Show result on std::cout
        std::cout << roster;

    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError. Could not open source file\n";
}
```